# Commit option in source control does not work properly in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github, git-commit

I have created an application, and I want to commit it to GitHub as as soon as I implement a new option. What I have noticed is that when I use the commit option under source control in Xcode, [image: Commit option under source control]

some commits appear in the GitHub website, while others don't, following is a clarification

The following figure shows the commits that appear in Xcode and the next one shows the commits appearing in the GitHub website. As you can notice "Added the Login with Facebook button" commit is missing, and any commit that I try to do after this one does not appear. What is the problem?

EDIT: What I have noticed is that I have two working copies of the same project. I doubt that I have created both, where the first copy has the remote GitHub link specified to it, while the other does not. I have tried to add the GitHub link to the second, but it creates more confusion than ever.
[image: Commits Appearing in Xcode]

[image: Commits Appearing in Github website]